# Unable to print specific nested json data with JSONSerialization

Tags: json, swift, string-parsing

I'm making an api call to get some data, the json dataAsString looks like this...

```
   guard let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)else {return}
     print(dataAsString)
```

JSON DATA

```
{"patch_report":{"name":"macOS Updates","patch_software_title_id":"1","total_computers":"5","total_versions":"1","versions":{"version":{"software_version":"10.15.3","computers":{"size":"5","computer":{"id":"467","name":"EPART1BGF8J9"}}}}}}
```

```
     do {
            // make sure this JSON is in the format we expect
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data, options:[]) as? [String: Any] {
                // try to read out a string array
                if let patch_report = json["patch_report"] as? [String] {
                    print(patch_report)
                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

**How could I use JSONSerialization to get only certain nested JSON values?**
I've been told by many not to use JSONSerialization so I've provided an alternate solution. Below has the Codable solution as well.
[Click Here For An Explination - Using Codable with nested JSON](https://medium.com/@nictheawesome/using-codable-with-nested-json-is-both-easy-and-fun-19375246c9ff)!

***I was able to find the answers below...***

**Get nested JSON using JSONSerialization**

```
        do {
            // make sure this JSON is in the format we expect
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data, options:[]) as? [String: Any] {
                // try to read out a string array
                if let patch_report = json["patch_report"] as? [String:Any] {
                    if let versions = patch_report["versions"] as? [String:Any] {
                        if let version = versions["version"] as? [String:Any] {
                            if let software_version = version["software_version"] as? String {
                                print(software_version)
                            }
                        }}

                }    else {print("Not Available")}
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

**Get nested Json using Decoder**

```
  struct PatchReport: Codable {

        var patch_report:Patch_report?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
            case patch_report = "patch_report"
        }

        struct Patch_report: Codable {

        var name:String?
        var patch_software_title_id:String?
        var total_computers:String?
        var total_versions:String?
        var versions: Versions?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case name = "name"
            case patch_software_title_id = "patch_software_title_id"
            case total_computers = "total_computers"
            case total_versions = "total_versions"
            case versions = "versions"
        }

        struct Versions: Codable {
            var version: Version?

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case version = "version"
            }


        struct Version: Codable {
            var software_version:String?
            var computers:Computers?

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case software_version = "software_version"
                case computers = "computers"
            }

            struct Computers: Codable{
                      var size:String?
                      var computer:Computer?

                enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                    case size = "size"
                    case computer = "computer"
                }

                struct Computer: Codable{
                    var id:String?
                    var name:String?

                    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                        case id = "id"
                        case name = "name"
                            }
                        }
                  }
            }
        }
    }
}
let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode(PatchReport.self, from: data)
print(String(response.patch_report?.total_computers ?? ""))
```

Comment: Abandon JSONSerialization.   Use Codable instead. Anyway `json["patch_report"]` is not a `[String]`. It’s a dictionary.

Comment: What would the Codable struct look like?

Comment: `if let patch_report = json["patch_report"] as? [String] { A() } else { B() }`, it's important that you know what can make it go to B() and what to A(). If `json["patch_report"]` is nil, go to B(). If `json["patch_report"]` is not a `[String]` (array of String), it will go to B(). Which reason do you think it is for you? That's important step in debugging and autonomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to cast `patch_report` as a `String` which won't work. Try this instead:

```
if let patch_report = json["patch_report"] as? [String: Any] {
    print(patch_report["name"])
}
```

Comment: How would I print,  patch_report > versions > version > name?

Comment: I would recommend using Codable instead, which makes it easier to access properties and child objects.